# How to check the default mail client

Tags: android, android-intent

How can I determine what is a default mail client on Adnroid? It could be for example standard Mail app or GMail appliction, how to know which one is configured as default?

Answer (score 2):

There is no concept of a "default mail client on Android".

There *is* a concept of a default app for a specific `Intent` structure. Hence, an `Intent` to send an email (e.g., `ACTION_SENDTO` with a `mailto:` `Uri`) may be tied to a default app. To find out what that default is, create the desired `Intent` and use `resolveActivity()` on `PackageManager`. This will come back with:

- The default app, if there is one
- A resolver activity (e.g., the system chooser), if there is no default and there is more than one choice
- The only email app, if there is only one choice
- `null`, if there are no matching activities

Or, use `PackageManager` and `getPreferredActivities()` and sift through those for things that you think are mail clients.

Comment: Nice one didn't that that was possible.

Comment: Thank you for response, however I always have Null as a result. I have set Gmail application as default using "Default App Manager". I tried using following intents: ACTION_SEND, ACTION_SENDTO to make a match with, but always getting Null. Do you have any idea what is a reason of that?

Comment: @OleksandrIvanov: "I have set Gmail application as default using "Default App Manager"" -- there is no "Default App Manager" in stock Android. This is something specific to your device. Hence, I cannot comment on it.

Comment: "Default App Manager" - this is application downloaded from google play

Comment: @OleksandrIvanov: I have no idea what that app's author thinks the app does. Apps cannot affect what apps are defaults.